# How to calculate current going through an LED

Tags: led, circuit-analysis

I'm a beginner to electronics. I want to find out how to calculate the current in the following circuit. (I know how to calculate total resister value in serial and parallel resisters in order to calculate the current, but is it possible to calculate without knowing the resister value of LED?)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuVYjd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: An ideal LED has no resistance.

Comment: @Majenko I'm pretty sure OP isn't using an ideal LED ;)

Comment: I'd answer this but I'm too old to do head-stands to look at that schematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use another technique that uses just circuit observation. For a simple circuit like this, I think it's easier than Thevenin.

The LED has a characteristic forward voltage, Vf. It varies with current, but the resistance in this circuit will keep the drop across the LED very close to the reported value in the datasheet. Let's use Vf = 2V for convenience.

Since the LED is parallel to R1, the voltage across R1 is also Vf. That must mean the drop across R2 is what's left over:
$$V_{R2} = 5V-V_f = 5V-2V=3V$$

Using Ohm's Law on R2:
$$I_{R2}=V_{R2}/100=30ma$$

Since R2 is in series with the source, that 30ma is the total current going into the circuit and is being split between R1 and the LED. We can figure out how much is going through R1 using Ohm's again.

$$I_{R1} = V_f/75= 2V/75 = 26.67ma$$

There's only 30ma going through the whole circuit and 26.67ma of it is going through the resistor. Therefore, only 3.3ma is left to go through the LED:

$$I_{LED} = 30ma - 26.67ma = 3.3ma$$

Comment: For a common led 3.3 mA not correspond with 2 V voltage drop...

Comment: Ok. Obviously I chose numbers out of pure convenience and not representative of any particular device. I believe the method and calculations are correct. I don't see how that justifies a downvote.

Comment: +1 for your technique. In the real world, there won't be any LED issues if Vf is measured.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Dan , but circuit simulator v1.6h shows as 32.86ma for IR2 , 22.86ma for IR1 and 10ma for Iled.is the simulator values wrong?   (here is the url for simulator software i used http://www.falstad.com/circuit/)

Comment: Well, what's the voltage drop across the LED you chose? I picked 2V arbitrarily, but each LED has it's own Vf. Replace 2V in the equations and it should work out.

Comment: Yes, I changed vf to 2V.(as shown in screenshot) http://imgur.com/DwQTcVp

Comment: Looks like the simulator solved for 1.71V across the LED. Look at Spehro's answer for a description of why the voltage across the LED changes as a function of current.

Comment: Ok,I will check

Comment: One small clarification, the correct value to get is the Vf value of the LED in order to calculate VR2, but the simulator has incorrectly taken the voltage difference through the LED to calculate this(Vd)?

Comment: The simulator isn't incorrect. It's just using a lookup table based on the current to determine the voltage drop. The Vf value of an LED is at only one specific current. Above or below that current, the voltage will be different. We shouldn't go into much more conversation here, so if you want to learn more about the voltage drop across a diode as a function of current, post a new question (or better yet, research it!).

Answer (score 9):

For the future (I doubt you need it now), I'll describe a more sophisticated approach that combines the Thevenin source with graphical (rather than using an equation) consideration of the nonlinear behavior of the LED.

1. Find the Thevenin equivalent as Martin suggests. You will find an equivalent voltage and an equivalent resistance. In this case it's 2.14V and 42.86\$\Omega\$.
2. Take a copy of the LED datasheet where it shows the Forward Current vs. Forward Bias. For example, the below, from [this datasheet](http://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS22-2000-223/S_110_LTST-C191KRKT.pdf).

[image]

The lowest voltage shown on the left side is 1.2V. The current from our Thevenin source would be (2.14V-1.2V)/42.86\$\Omega\$ = 21.93mA. Mark that on the axis. Now draw a diagonal line from that point to the Thevenin equivalent voltage. This is called a **load line**. Where it crosses the LED curve tells you the LED current and votlage when it it connected to the source- as so:

[image]

What if they don't cross (or only appear to cross very close to 0mA)? Then the LED will not light. Try this with a blue LED characteristic curve and you'll see that it won't light. This should make sense to you, since you know from the Thevenin calculation that when the LED is removed (the highest voltage you'll see) the voltage will be only 2.14V (and that's not enough to light a blue LED).

And if the line is off the top, that probably means your LED will fry.

This is the old-school way of finding the operating point when have (a) nonlinear element(s). In 2014 most folks would probably fire up a simulator, which is good when it produces correct results (but they're only as correct as the models accurately reflect reality and as well as the the simulation is set up).

Comment: Excellent answer. Old school is just right sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

You must replace the lineal part of the circuit (i.e. two resistors and source) with a [Thevenin's equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin's_theorem).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiNgQp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where

$$
R_{th} = \dfrac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\\
V_{th} = \dfrac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\cdot V_{BAT1}
$$

Then, if for example, this is a red led, you can assume 1.2 V of voltage drop trough it,

$$
I_{LED}=I_{Rth}=\dfrac{V_{th}-1.2\,\mathrm{V}}{R_{th}}
$$

Obviously, more complex networks, involve other values ​​of \$R_{th}\$ and \$V_{th}\$. It is advisable to learn this method, as it allows you to find the operating point for nonlinear elements, when it is determined by linear elements.